# How to change Label in For loop

Tags: .net, vb.net

How realize this in vb.net?

In vba(Excel) i use:

```
For i = 1 To 5
UserFrom1.Controls("Label" & i).Visible = False
Next
```

How do it in VB.net? I try thus:

```
Me.Controls("Label" & i).Visible = True
```

If labels are in diferent Form, like Form3.Controls("Label" & i).Visible = True, its work perfectly
How use it in this same form?

VS2013 return: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in app.exe

Comment: start by turning on `Option Strict`; then debug your code

Comment: what is your current form name e.g `Form1` or something. Can you try that instead of `Me`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

hi you should hide your code under try catch statement

```
    Try
        Form1.Controls("Label" & i).Visible = False
    Catch ex As Exception
        'execute code when there is no valid label element found just ignore error
    End Try
```

this should work good luck